# How do we handle tags with the same Acronym?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/337991/struggling-with-sas-procedure-and-data) asks about the [SAS statistics software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_programming_language) as opposed to the more general usage - of the hard drive interface known as Serial Attached SCSI. I don't think the question-asker's at fault, since the tag for [sas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas) has no wiki or excerpt attached. However, if we were to have the two tags split, how would we do it? The acronym is appropriate for both topics, both use the same acronyms in common use,  no one would know what the stretched out form of Serial Attached Scsi without looking for it and SAS dosen't expand to anything when it comes to the software.

Not very likely it'll happen too often, but i'm not sure what would be the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: SAS Software. Done deal.

Answer (score 2):

There are 11 questions tagged [sas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas).

- 2 of those are for the application
- 9 are for Serial Attached SCSI drives.

It seems to me that the case is clear. Even if SAS questions were server-centric, if we haven't migrated them to Server Fault then why shouldn't the tag exist?

Therefore:

- Leave [sas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas) for Serial Attached SCSI and create a tag excerpt
- Create [sas-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-software) for  the application and also create a tag excerpt. Retag the two questions. Maybe you could also use [sas-analytics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-analytics), as this is something the software vendor [commonly uses](http://www.sas.com/software/), or [sas-statistics-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-statistics-software)?

Comment: i'd suggest sas-statistics-software might be more precise.

Comment: Either way! I added it, let's see what people prefer.

Comment: hm, sas-analytics looks better

Comment: +1 for sas-analytics

Answer (score 1):

Use [sa-scsi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sa-scsi) for Serial Attached SCSI, it still auto-completes and is more clear.

Use [sas-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-software), you might not want to use `analytics` because they seem to have more than just that, we don't want a bunch of `sas-` tags for all the different types of computer-based solutions they provide. Although the tag wiki should be explanatory, doing a simple Google for [sas-software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-software) clearly tells me what this tag is about so this should be enough to fix the acronym problem. If you'd go for [sas-analytics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sas-analytics), it's also fine with me as I wanted to suggest [sa-scsi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sa-scsi) anyway...

Answer (score 0):

SAS is extremely server-centric so I expect this to be a non-issue on Super User, those questions largely belong on Server Fault almost by definition.

Comment: I disagree – the questions are still here, and the majority uses `[sas]` for the drives (*not* the application).

Comment: regardless, any SAS questions here about the software or hardware should be crazily rare on Super User. Software belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/sas and Hardware belongs on http://serverfault.com/tags/sas -- it's really that simple. So whichever one you like, but really it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then we should probably go through the questions and migrate or close them and inform the users when they pop up again?